# Writing data in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, opencsv

I want to get rid of manually writing the data into a list every time and automate the process. The data would be coming from a csv file. I just want to be able to call on to the file and the data becomes part of the list so I can use that. This is what I have as my code.

```
lista1=['number','number','AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','number','number','AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','number','number','AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD']
lista2=[1,1,10,11,12,13,1,1,14,15,16,17,1,1,18,19,20,21]
lista_final = []
for i in range(len(lista1)):
    if lista1[i] == 'AAA':
        print('AAA',lista2[i])
    if lista1[i] == 'BBB':
        print('BBB',lista2[i])
    if lista1[i] == 'CCC':
            print('CCC',lista2[i])
    if lista1[i] == 'DDD':
        print('DDD',lista2[i])
```

Sample Data:

| AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |

Output:

| AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |

My main concern still is to get the sample data into the list instead of actually writing down the values like `'AAA' 'BBB'`

Comment: Could you give an example of the final result you are expecting? The if-print statements are not very clear.

Comment: You mention a CSV file, but your code doesn't read from a file.  Please define your problem clearly by providing sample input and the desired output that you would like to have produced from that input.  If you will be reading data from a CSV file, provide the content for a sample CSV file and the output that you want to see for that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Python's [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) which provides you with tooling for easy csv-reading and -writing.

Example from the docs for reading:

```py
import csv

with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:

    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

    for row in spamreader:

        print(', '.join(row))
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

and for writing:

```py
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```